# Update cookies with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'me a noob on AngularJS. I'm trying to manage cookies but it doesn't works as I want. I've two version of this code that seams identical but if the first one works... The second one failed.

The code for my login form is here :

```js
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('userApp', ['suiviChantiers', 'ngCookies']);

    app.controller('UserLogin', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookies',
        function($scope, $http, $cookies) {

          $scope.login = function() {
            $scope.user = this.user;

            $http.post('services/user.php', {
              action: 'login',
              user: $scope.user
            }).success(function(data) {
              if (data.error) {
                // [...]
              } else if (data.message == 'success') {
                $cookies.user = data.data;
                console.log("User : " + $cookies.user); // Output is : User : MS1OVFEwWkRZeU5ETTBNVFV3TVE9PQ==
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                  if ($cookies.redirectTo == null) {
                    document.location.href = "chantier/index.html";
                  } else {
                    var dest = $cookies.redirectTo;
                    $cookies.redirectTo = null;
                    document.location.href = dest;
                  }
                }, 3000);
              }
            });
          };
          // [...]
        })();
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<h1>Login form ...</h1>
```

And in my "chantier/index.html" controller I have this :

```js
(function() {
 var app = angular.module('chantierApp', ['ngCookies']);
 
 app.controller('ChantierListController', ['$scope', '$cookies', 'userService', function($scope, $cookies, userService) {
  $scope.user = userService.user;
  console.log("User : "+$cookies.user); // Output is : User : undefined but $cookies.redirectTo is not empty

 }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

(Sorry for this so long code post)
Can you explain me why cookies are not updated?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I solved my problem ... Everything was ok. But there was some very very persistent cache on some files (even after deleting cache files and tmp files).
I launched my browser in private mode and everything worked.

Thanks for your help.